# How to put error message into if statement if(...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, if-statement

[image]I'm trying to get an ajax response from a facial recogntionAPI. The response is the data feature of a face, 
the error message is

> {"Errors":[{"Message":"no faces found in the image","ErrCode":5002}]}

The response message is

> {"images":[{"status":"Complete","width":236,}]}]}

How should I write the If/else statement so that I can alert "success" if there's a face/response, and alert "fail" if there isn't face/error?

```html
$("#testDetect").click(function () {
    var file = $('#imageFile')[0].files[0]; 
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      var imageData = parseImageData(reader.result);
      var data = {};
      data.image = imageData;
      $.ajax({
      url      : "http://localhost/Karios/simple-detect/form-post.php",
      type     : "POST",
      data     :  data,
      dataType : 'text'
   }).done(function(response) {

     console.log(response);

            if (!response) { 

                alert('Hmm, unexpected response from Kairos');
            } else if (response['Errors'] && response['Errors'].size() > 0) { 
                if (response['Errors'][0]['ErrCode'] == 5002) { 

                    alert(response['Errors'][0]['Message']);

                } else {

                    alert('Some other error occurred:\n' + response['Errors']['ErrorCode'] + ': ' + response['Errors']['Message']);

                }
                
            } else { 

                alert('Face(s) detected');
      }  
    })
    }
});
```

if there is a face and alert "fail" if there isn't a face

Comment: and what response you are getting when there is no error

Comment: the object you are passing to ajax call, you can pass two more field `error` and `success`, these both are callbacks. when there is any error the error callback will be called else the success callback. this way you know exactly where the to handle error.

Comment: @UjjwalKumarGupta If they send me the response, I want to alert "success". If they send me the error, I want to alert "fail".

Comment: @nurulnabi Thanks for replying! Since I'm new to programming, I have no idea what you talking about... Could you please write the code out for me? thanks!

Comment: @JimmyLiao, have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually jquery gives a .done and .fail for each, so :

```
    $.ajax({
              url      : "http://localhost/Karios/simple-detect/form-post.php",
              type     : "POST",
              data     :  data,
              dataType : 'text'
           }).done(function(response) {
    try {
let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
      if(jsonResponse.Errors && jsonResponse.Errors[0] && jsonResponse.Errors[0].ErrCode ===5002) {alert(jsonResponse.Errors[0].Message);}
    } catch(err) { console.log("bad response");}
                alert( "success" );
           })
          .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
          })
          .always(function() {
            alert( "complete" );
          });
```

Comment: ahh, but what if failure doesn't mean ajax failure, rather an indication of failure returned in the response?

Comment: Have edited the code to check for the error code and then print the message accordingly.

Comment: this new code assumes response is an object - as datatype == `text` - the response will be text :p (I'm a pain in the backside)

Comment: You're going to hate me ... what if the non fail response isn't JSON :p (I can go like this all day, my wife does this to me all the time) - damn, didn't see the try catch - you're ahead of me :p or , are you?

Comment: Good that I didn't marry either of you :P. Well the response in this case must be JSON for this error code at least as per the author of the question. So, I should be good to assume that.

Comment: of course, it'd be far simpler for the API to respond with a 4xx status :p in case of failure

Comment: That would be simple. But 4xx status is too harsh for an actual response. Instead I'd love api to return data in JSON. with error null or value as per the case.

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: @JimmyLiao well can you please add the result of "console.log(response);" without quotes?

Comment: what does console.log(typeof response) says?

Comment: Check the image I posted

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#testDetect").click(function () {
    var file = $('#imageFile')[0].files[0]; 
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      var imageData = parseImageData(reader.result);
      var data = {};
      data.image = imageData;
      $.ajax({
      url      : "http://localhost/Karios/simple-detect/form-post.php",
      type     : "POST",
      data     :  data,
      dataType : 'text',
      success:function(response){
        alert('success');       //do your stuff here on success
      },
      error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('fail');          //do your stuff here on fail
      }
   })
  }
})
```

Have a look on the `error` and `success` callback. when the ajax request resolves successfully the `success` callback will be called indicating the request is successful and the result will be contained in the `response` else the `error` callback will be called.

Comment: Didn't work... I uploaded a picture of what I saw in console, I think that might help

Comment: remove the `dataType` field. And this is the correct syntax as per official documentation if anything wrong happening then you need to figure out where is that happening.

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose the `Errors` key is only present when there is not a match.

```
{"Errors":[{"Message":"no faces found in the image","ErrCode":5002}]}
```

One way is:

```
if(response.Errors){
    alert("fail!"); // or you can return the error message
}else{
    alert("success");
}
```

If the response always contains an `Errors` key then:

```
if(response.Errors.length > 0){ 
    // fail 
} else { 
     //success 
}
```

Comment: I uploaded a picture of what I saw in console, I think that might help

Answer (score 0):

```
      $.ajax({
      url      : "http://localhost/Karios/simple-detect/form-post.php",
      type     : "POST",
      data     :  data,
      dataType : 'text'
   }).done(function(response) {

      if(response.Errors)
      {
      alert("fail!");
      console.log(response.Errors.Message)
    }
    else{
    alert('success!');
    }
      console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: then there ma be a chance that you are still getting errors in the json response. It will be better if you can supply both the error response and success resonse.

Comment: Check out the image that I posted

Comment: please try this - 

if(!response.images)
      {
      alert("fail!");
      console.log(response.Errors.Message)
    }
    else{
    alert('success!');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use handlers for [AJAX Events](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) instead of response parsing. It is possible using [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) registration.
For example, remove the `.done()` method and append the code below to your javascript:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  alert("AJAX request is success!");
});
$(document).ajaxError(function() {
  alert("AJAX request completes with an error.");
});
```

Or handle local events:

```
$.ajax({
   // ...
   success: function(){
     alert("AJAX request is success!");
   },
   error: function(){
     alert("AJAX request completes with an error.");
   }
 });
```

Comment: Could you write the code out for me plz? I'm new to programming :)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: TRACKING_NAME is not defined

Comment: @JimmyLiao, Is the `global` property in [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) is true? Note, that global events are never fired for cross-domain script!